# How do I implement my own @Tranactional aware service in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I'm writing an app that may talk to multiple database and web services. I'd like to use Spring's @Transactional annotation so that a failure in any one can rollback them all.

I'm not clear about how I should do this, and I can't find any examples of it either after searching.

One thought I have is to create a bean that is a custom aspect and use that to intercept the methods, adding my own custom code to rollback problems. But I'm sure there must be a way to do this in a standardised fashion.

Thank you!

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way to implement distributed transactions is JTA, but I don't think it's feasible in your case, because you also need to cover web services.

However, you can implement a "best effort" solution manually by registering [`TransactionSynchronization`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronization.html)s for your transactional resources. This way you can integrate them with `@Transactional`.

See [`TransactionSynchronizationManager`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationManager.html).

Comment: This looks like the right kind of thing. I'm assuming I register myself when I do an transaction, and Spring will callback afterCompletetion(..) when I need to rollback. I can then schedule a message a message to the web service to rollback the work it did.

Comment: Here we are: http://azagorneanu.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/transaction-synchronization-callbacks.html

Answer (score 0):

you should have something like below declared in your spring config xml for each of the datasource to be able to use @Transactional in your application:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Moreover, if you are using multiple databases, maybe you should use XA-Datasources